# Installing Ubuntu on HP Omen Desktop

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, hp, bios, ahci

I recently decided to try installing Ubuntu on my PC (an HP Omen 25L desktop) alongside Windows 10 to dual boot. The system has two drives: an SSD for the OS and a larger HDD for data storage. When I try installing Ubuntu from a USB, it doesn't detect the SSD and tries to install on the HDD, which is obviously not what I want. Poking around, I found that this is often because Windows systems with multiple drives have a RAID configuration rather than AHCI, which Ubuntu apparently doesn't like. However, I cannot find any options in the BIOS to change this.

My question is this: is installing Ubuntu on this device even possible, or has HP foiled me once again?

Comment: Yes, you need to change SATA (or drive or whatever HP decided) mode to AHCI. Please read your user's manual. Don't forget to install AHCI support in Windows before making the change.

Comment: Similar:  HP OMEN 15-dh0 UEFI update
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2448563
HP OMEN 15-ce0xx
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2407145 & 
http://martinsosic.com/linux/2015/03/01/arch-linux-on-hp-omen.html &
https://jeanbruenn.info/2018/04/01/omen-hp-with-linux/

Comment: @ChanganAuto The user's manual for the computer does not include instructions on how to do that, as far as I can tell. It's mostly concerned with the basics (setting it up, turning it on, how to call HP for support, etc.)